# Comparing Groups in data.table Columns

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I have a dataset that I need to both split by one variable (`Day`) and then compare between groups of another variable (`Group`), performing per-group statistics (e.g. `mean`) and also tests.

Here's an example of what I devised:

```
require(data.table)
data = data.table(Day = rep(1:10, each = 10), 
                  Group = rep(1:2, times = 50),
                  V = rnorm(100))

data[, .(g1_mean = mean(.SD[Group == 1]$V),
         g2_mean = mean(.SD[Group == 2]$V),
         p.value = t.test(V ~ Group, .SD, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value),
     by = list(Day)]
```

Which produces:

```
    Day      g1_mean     g2_mean   p.value
 1:   1  0.883406048  0.67177271 0.6674138
 2:   2  0.007544956 -0.55609722 0.3948459
 3:   3  0.409248637  0.28717183 0.8753213
 4:   4 -0.540075365  0.23181458 0.1785854
 5:   5 -0.632543900 -1.09965990 0.6457325
 6:   6 -0.083221671 -0.96286343 0.2011136
 7:   7 -0.044674252 -0.27666473 0.7079499
 8:   8  0.260795244 -0.15159164 0.4663712
 9:   9 -0.134164758  0.01136245 0.7992453
10:  10  0.496144329  0.76168408 0.1821123
```

I'm hoping that there's a less roundabout manner of arriving at this result.

Comment: You can use `dcast` to get the mean i.e. `dcast(data, Day~Group, value.var='V', mean)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible compact alternative which can also apply more functions to each group:

```
DTnew <- dcast(DT[, pval := t.test(V ~ Group, .SD, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value, Day],
               Day + pval ~ paste0("g",Group), fun = list(mean,sd), value.var = "V")
```

which gives:

```
> DTnew
    Day      pval   V_mean_g1    V_mean_g2   V_sd_g1   V_sd_g2
 1:   1 0.4763594 -0.11630634  0.178240714 0.7462975 0.4516087
 2:   2 0.5715001 -0.29689807  0.082970631 1.3614177 0.2745783
 3:   3 0.2295251 -0.48792449 -0.031328749 0.3723247 0.6703694
 4:   4 0.5565573  0.33982242  0.080169698 0.5635136 0.7560959
 5:   5 0.5498684 -0.07554433  0.308661427 0.9343230 1.0100788
 6:   6 0.4814518  0.57694034  0.885968245 0.6457926 0.6773873
 7:   7 0.8053066  0.29845913  0.116217727 0.9541060 1.2782210
 8:   8 0.3549573  0.14827289 -0.319017581 0.5328734 0.9036501
 9:   9 0.7290625 -0.21589411 -0.005785092 0.9639758 0.8859461
10:  10 0.9899833  0.84034529  0.850429982 0.6645952 1.5809149
```

*A decomposition of the code*:

- First, a `pval` variable is added to the dataset with `DT[, pval := t.test(V ~ Group, .SD, alternative = "two.sided")$p.value, Day]`
- Because `DT` is updated in place and by reference by the previous step, the `dcast` function can be applied to that directly.
- In the casting formula, you specify the variables that need to stay in the current form on the RHS and the variable that needs to be spread over columns on the LHS.
- With the `fun` argument you can specify which aggregation function has to be used on the `value.var` (here `V`). If multiple aggregation functions are needed, you can specify them in a list (e.g. `list(mean,sd)`). This can be any type of function. So, also cumstom made functions can be used.

If you want to remove the `V_` from the column names, you can do:

```
names(DTnew) <- gsub("V_","",names(DTnew))
```

---

*NOTE: I renamed the `data.table` to `DT` as it is often not wise to name your dataset after a function (check `?data`)*

Comment: This looks like a lovely solution @Jaap, would you be kind enough to explain how the first line works?

Comment: @thomasfedb Added an explanation. HTH

Comment: Thanks @Jaap, that's very helpful, particular knowing now that `:=` is for adding additional variables to data tables.

Answer (score 1):

While not a one-liner, you might consider doing your two processes separate and then merging the results. This prevents you from having to hardcode the group-names.

First, we calculate the means:

```
my_means <- dcast(data[,mean(V), by = .(Day, Group)],
                  Day~ paste0("Mean_Group", Group),value.var="V1")
```

Or in the less-convoluted way @Akrun mentioned in the comments, with some added formatting.

```
my_means <- dcast(Day~paste0("Mean_Group", Group), data=data,
              fun.agg=mean, value.var="V")
```

Then the t-tests:

```
t_tests <- data[,.(p_value=t.test(V~Group)$p.value), by = Day]
```

And then merge:

```
output <- merge(my_means, t_tests)
```

Comment: I think OP's `data.table` approach is more straight forward than this

Comment: I think in the current version, yes. But it might be more consise in the event of multiple tests/descriptive statistics.

Comment: How would you expand this to also find the `sd` of each group while keeping things concise?